# Incorrect Power Calculation in MATLAB Convolution

Tags: matlab, convolution, random-process, signal-power

I have been working on a MATLAB code to perform convolution and calculate the power of the resulting signal. However, I have encountered an issue with the power calculation in my code.

I am convolving two signals, signal1 and signal2, and I know the power of signal1 (input_power) and the desired output power (output_power). The code aims to scale signal1 and signal2 accordingly, perform the convolution, and calculate the power of the resulting signal.

However, the calculated power does not match the expected output power. I suspect there might be an error in my code logic.

Here is the code I have been using:

```
% Known parameters
input_power = 3; % Known power of one signal
output_power = 6; % Known output power

% Generate random signals
signal1 = randn(1, 100);
signal2 = randn(1, 100);

% Calculate power scaling factor
scaling_factor = sqrt(output_power / input_power);

% Scale signal1 and signal2 with the calculated scaling factor
scaled_signal1 = sqrt(input_power) * signal1;
scaled_signal2 = scaling_factor * signal2;

% Convolve the two signals
convolved_signal = conv(scaled_signal1, scaled_signal2);

% Calculate the power of the convolved signal
convolved_signal_power = sum(abs(convolved_signal).^2) / length(convolved_signal);

% Display the calculated power and verify if it matches the given output power
disp(['Calculated output power: ', num2str(convolved_signal_power)]);
disp(['Given output power: ', num2str(output_power)]);
```

When running this code, the calculated `output power (convolved_signal_power)` does not match the given `output power (output_power)`. The calculated power seems to be significantly higher.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this discrepancy and how to correctly calculate the power of the convolved signal.

Edit: In short, I wanted to know **the relationship between the convolved output signal power with the power of its two input signals**.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You seem to assume that the power of two signals multiply together when convolving. I don’t see why this would be the case. As far as I know, the only way to know the resulting power is to compute the convolution, but I might be wrong. For example, if two signals have all their power in disjoint frequency bands, then their convolution will have zero power.

Comment: @Marcus: if something doesn't meet "expectation" you should clearly state what these expectations, where they come from and what assumptions are associated with them . As Cris has already pointed out: most likely that's the issue here. Assumptions are important: continuous vs discrete. Finite vs infinite length. Power signals vs Energy signals etc.